# Retrieve query params with Flask-RESTful

Tags: flask, query-string, postman, flask-restful

I have a flask-RESTful endpoint defined by:

```
class SearchEvents(Resource):
    def get(self, name, start_date, end_date):
         #do stuff

api.add_resource(endpoints.SearchEvents, '/events/<string:name>/<string:start_date>/<string:end_date>')
```

I'm testing it manually with Postman. I'd like to pass in null values for start_date and end_date. However:

[image: screenshot of postman interface]
I've tried modifying the url to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/events/test/ /  #<--Spaces
```

and

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/events/test/""/""
```

To no avail.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ended up solving this by using the flask-restful `request` object, which has an `args` property which retrieves query params from the request url:

```
from flask_restful import request #import request from flask restful

class SearchEvents(Resource):
    def get(self):
        args = request.args #retrieve args from query string

api.add_resource(endpoints.SearchEvents, '/events')
```

And then making the requests like: `http://127.0.0.1:5000/events?param1=value1&param2=value2`
Or to pass null values: `http://127.0.0.1:5000/events?param=&param2=value1`

Comment: I noticed the get function now only passes the `self` attribute, why did you have to remove all the query parameters (`name`, `start_date`, `end_date`)?

Comment: This top answer is flawed. I would have liked to know the type of the variable `args` as in `args = request.args`. How to use it? Is it a dict or a class with properties for each param? And so on. Readers need to try in debug or dig in the documentation to then be confident of the type with trial and error rather than knowing it already.

Answer (score 2):

The values you are passing are not in the query string. You are using route parts as parameters so the route does not get matched unless you supply something of the form `/events/some_name/2019-86-98/2100-9885-24515`. The attempts you made are catched by flask as non matching routes and you get 404 not found.

To send those parameters as part of the query string would be to use something like 
`/events?name=some_name&start_date=2019-86-98&end_date=2100-9885-24515` and to get the values in your route handlers you should use `name = request.args.get('name')` and so on. Passing null values then means hitting the same url but without the query parameters.

Comment: I have come to realize this, but am not able to find a way to implement this in Flask-RESTful: when I put the query string in the endpoint url, Postman requests including the correct syntax get a 404 whether I supply values or not. Not sure whether you're familiar with flask-RESTful or not but I would appreciate some pointers on this

Comment: I am very familiar with flask-restplus but asking for pointers is not going to get you answers. Ask a concrete question or post a piece of code when you say something is not working, else it is imposible to help you.
To begin with, you should change the way you register your resource to `api.add_resource(endpoints.SearchEvents, '/events')` or it will not get hit when you use postman to make a request to `127.0.0.1:5000/events`. Start from something basic by removing all parameters and build up from there.